# Etsy API - Domestic & Global Pricing

Tags: etsy, etsyapi

Is there a way to toggle Domestic & Global Pricing feature with Etsy API?

I checked [Etsy API reference](https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/reference) and I can't find anything about this parameter.

Etsy enabled this option suddenly in my country and gave no option to change it in bulk. I have few thousands listings where I need to disable this option and don't want to do it manually.